# Errors Installing Wine

Tags: wine

I installed Ubuntu 19.04 this morning and i've been trying to download lots of apps but its challenging and frustrating but not like wine.So these are my errors

```
root@miarhpe:/home/ephraim# sudo apt-add-repository 'deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ disco main' 
Ign:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/noobslab/apps/ubuntu disco InRelease            
Ign:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-security InRelease               
Hit:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/videolan/master-daily/ubuntu disco InRelease    
Err:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-security Release                 
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
Hit:5 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu disco InRelease                 
Ign:6 http://ng.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco InRelease                      
Ign:7 http://ng.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-updates InRelease              
Ign:8 http://ng.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-backports InRelease            
Ign:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/atom/ubuntu disco InRelease         
Err:10 http://ng.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
Err:11 http://ng.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-updates Release               
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
Err:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/noobslab/apps/ubuntu disco Release      
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Err:13 http://ng.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-backports Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
Err:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/atom/ubuntu disco Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Reading package lists... Done
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-1386/Packages' as repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/videolan/master-daily/ubuntu disco InRelease' doesn't support architecture '1386'
E: The repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-security Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-1386/Packages' as repository 'https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu disco InRelease' doesn't support architecture '1386'
E: The repository 'http://ng.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://ng.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-updates Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/noobslab/apps/ubuntu disco Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://ng.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-backports Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/atom/ubuntu disco Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Please help me out what's going wrong

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install software or upgrade from an old unsupported release?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release)

Answer (score -1):

You need not go into all that trouble.

May I suggest, work from your personal account, not root. Whatever root privilege you 'll need, obtain with sudo.

Try the following:

```
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:whateveryouadded
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt install -f
sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt install wine32 wine64
```

You should be able to run wine with no problem afterwards.

Hope I have helped :)

Comment: The problem is with the repositories being moved as 19.04 is unsupported. That won't solve it

Comment: I would upgrade to 20.04. 19.04 gave me various problems as well, I had to switch back to 18.04, before 20.04 LTS.

Comment: so @Sasuke Uchiha isn't there any way around it ?

Comment: @Giorgos Saridakis this is how we're looking             
 `root@miarhpe:/home/ephraim# sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa: 'deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ disco main'
Error: need a single repository as argument`

Comment: remove the repository as suggested in the answer below. but that's the least of your problems now.

Comment: @Ephraim-the-program why don't you just upgrade to 20.04? that is the best way

Comment: @GiorgosSaridakis wow ! how far does it really go ?

Comment: @Ephraim-the-program well there is a way. See https://askubuntu.com/a/91821/1073514

Comment: i'll take your advice @GiorgosSaridakis i'll get the new release and give a feedback tomorrow or next..Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Your best approach would be a step-by-step troubleshooting procedure.

Step 1:

1. Open **Softwares & Updates**
2. Note the error message if any
3. Navigate to the **Other Software's** tab
4. Remove ppa and or ng/security software which were in the error

Step 2:

Open Terminal and type/input:

1. `sudo apt-get clean`
2. `sudo apt-get update`
3. `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`

Step 3:

Retry the wine installation

Within the Terminal type/input:

1. `sudo apt update && sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-stable`

Comment: This won't help. Disco Dingo (19.04) release has met its EOL and the repositories are no longer available.

Comment: @Ephraim-the-program I would suggest following karel 's comment to upgrading to 20.04 to the original question.

Answer (score -1):

You dont need to add a PPA just do "sudo apt install wine"!

Comment: Hi there, thanks for contibuting. PPAs often contain more up to date versions than the Ubuntu repos, especially with something like `wine`, where support for various features is always evolving.

Comment: Ok, Got it! Thanks for notifying me of my mistakes!